# Slow text search query with Postgres 10.6

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I am using Postgres 10.6 and I have a table with around 30M addresses that I have merged in one column (`textsearch`):

```
create table my_addresses as 
    SELECT 
    concat_ws(' ', my_text_id, full_address, postcode, business_name) as address, 
    to_tsvector('english', concat_ws(' ', my_text_id, full_address, postcode, business_name)) as textsearch 
    from my_data;
```

On top of it I have created an index with

```
CREATE INDEX ON my_addresses USING GIN (textsearch);
```

What I am trying to achieve is a free text search (Google like) where I can input any text and picking up the top 10 of the most similar addresses.
So I am querying with:

```
SELECT address, similarity('flat 11 peabody se17 1bt', address) AS simil
FROM my_addresses
select * from x
ORDER BY simil DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

The query looks ok as result but it is very very slow and it looks like is not even using the index.

So I have created an alternative index, this time based on the `address` field in this way:

```
CREATE INDEX ON my_addresses  USING GIN (address gin_trgm_ops);
```

and changed the query like this:

```
SELECT address, similarity('flat 11 peabody se17 1bt', address) AS simil
FROM my_addresses
where addresses % 'flat 11 peabody se17 1bt'
ORDER BY simil DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This time is using the index but it still very slow (around 1 minute).

So I have tried a new index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON my_addresses  USING GIST (address gist_trgm_ops);
```

and changed again the query like this:

```
SELECT address, address <-> 'flat 11 peabody se17 1bt' AS dist
FROM my_addresses
ORDER BY dist LIMIT 10;
```

but it is still very slow.

Is there a way to make this sort of query fast?

Comment: Hi there. I did this [**question**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91171/how-operator-work) for geometric distance sometime ago, but i guess is similar for string similarity. See how I use the `<->` operator first limit the result to 100 and then sort. Right now you calculate the distance and then sort everything. That is very slow because the sort doesn't use index. But if you use only the `<->` operator first you will use the index

Comment: I tried but I cannot see the difference. Also the geometric distance with '<->' is base on tessellation so it is approximate I guess which cannot be got from text.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza well actually u r right :) even without out er query I put the distance in the order. It looks better not super fast but better - thanks

Comment: Glad to help. Now you need to check the `EXPLAIN PLAN` and maybe you can improve the performance with a proper index

Comment: I am doing `vacuum analyze` first

Comment: still 4-5 seconds which is better but not good enough :(